# Is there any way to get access to Live Agent status?

Tags: liveagent, streaming-api

The LiveAgent Supervisor Tab makes has access to a streaming API that updates as agents come on and offline. However, I haven't been able to find any documented APIs that allow for this.

I'm working on an internal dashboard to monitor Live Agent status and essentially make a more advanced version of the Supervisor Tab.

I've looked into LiveAgentSession but it appears that it only gets created once a session is ended.

Is the Supervisor tab using undocumented APIs?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to Stackexchange! Yes, it is something related to salesforce internal architecture and not exposed i think.

Comment: I have been trying to do the same without luck. I hope they expose those APIs at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It does appear that they are not exposed for easy consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently exposed in the API as of Winter 2014 Release.